# Unable to integrate Mongo-Service-Management in CAS 4.2.0

Tags: mongodb, cas

i do not know Java and i'm a newbie with CAS. in the CAS documentations there is an example for MongoDb-Authentication(by example i mean a code sample that i should write inside cas.properties), but for Mongo-Service-Management, there is not any example.

[MongoDb-Authentication](http://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/MongoDb-Authentication.html)

```
cas.authn.mongo.collection.name=users
cas.authn.mongo.db.host=mongodb://user:password@ds061954.somewhere.com:61954/database
cas.authn.mongo.attributes=attribute1,attribute2
cas.authn.mongo.username.attribute=username
cas.authn.mongo.password.attribute=password
```

i did as such and it's working. (i didn't change the third line though, i don't know what it is.)

but in the [Mongo-Service-Management](http://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Mongo-Service-Management.html) documentation

```
mongodb.host=mongodb database url
mongodb.port=mongodb database port
mongodb.userId=mongodb userid to bind
mongodb.userPassword=mongodb password to bind
cas.service.registry.mongo.db=Collection name to store service definitions
```

now here we have `cas.service.registry.mongo.db` so it's probably the name of our db, but they say it's a Collection name. is that a typo?
should the url include the port, the username and password and the name of the database?
the below code is what i did, and it made the `/cas` path to return `404 Not Found`!

```
mongodb.host=mongodb://myUserName:myPassword@ds061360.mlab.com:61360/mydb
mongodb.port=61360
mongodb.userId=mydb.myUserName
mongodb.userPassword=myPassword
cas.service.registry.mongo.db=services
mongodb.timeout=5000
```

as i said this make CAS to be unavailable, so i tried changing the url by removing the username and password, or db name, or the port from the url, none of them works.
the `_id` of the database user in mlab.com is `mydb.myUserName`, i changed it to `myUserName` but this didn't help either. can you provide an example or explain what am i doing wrong?

thank you for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: If CAS Server is going unavailable I'd check the cas.log file. It should contain the cause of the error.

Comment: it was a bug: https://github.com/apereo/cas/issues/1891